# How to wait in a fragment until thread is done in another Activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I want to wait until thread is finished in one Activity, and pass somehow method 'onPostExecute()' to another Fragment. Basically one Activity is saving bitmap asynchronously on internal storage, and the Fragment is loading the same bitmap, then trying to do some conversion on it.

I've no clue how to make these things work. I'm not looking for an full ready code or smth, just some advice.

Below my concept:

[image]

Comment: Start the fragment with an intent in `onPostExecute` and pass the Bitmap URI as an extra

Comment: @PsyGik well thank you very much for your answer. It is somehow an answer for my question but not exaclty. I've made saving a file asynchronous because i've wanted to achieve nice user experience. So.. meanwhile the bitmap is saving, an fragment is already displayed.

Comment: In that case you can use a Publisher/Subscriber model. Subscribe to the event of the bitmap being saved, and Publish when the task is done. You can take a look at EventBus for achieving this.

Comment: Is the Activity required to save the Bitmap or start the AsyncTask? Why can't the Fragment do that?

Comment: @cricket_007 User has two options in one activity 'browse gallery' and 'pick image by a camera', when he choose his option, onActivityResult() triggers in this Activity. Whole app has few fragments in a form of tabs. You can choose through tabs (fragments) few operations on the picked image, like some simple conversions, rotation or anything else. Basiclly each fragment has it's own logic and purpose.

Comment: Okay based on your previous comment, it seems that the best course of action is indeed wait on the `onPostExecute` method and then launch the activities containing the fragment with the image URI as an intent extra.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing your processing in an AsyncTask you can wait for it to finish by calling 'get':

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: That will freeze the UI. Not recommended. Better to use interface callbacks or EventBus to push the completion rather than wait

Comment: @cricket_007 not if you call it in another AsyncTask

Comment: Sure, but using `get` within an AsyncTask for the result of another AsyncTask seems pointless

Comment: @cricket_007 it's not pointless, it's specifically to prevent the UI from freezing. Plus the poster says they want to perform some processing of the bitmap after its been saved, they can use the second AsyncTask to do this once get returns.

Comment: Okay, maybe not "pointless", but there's better ways than forcing AsyncTask back to synchronous. That's my only argument

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for sth. to complete in an activity or Fragment is generally not a good idea because it would freeze UI and the user may get frustrated by it. Nevertheless you can store the thread reference in a singleton for example and subscripe on the onPostExecute from the newly started fragment